# Running powershell script from solution explorer inside Nuget Package Manager Console

Tags: c#, powershell, nuget

I have a few powershell scripts inside my c# project. I added them to a solution folder. Would it be possible to make VS2010 run them inside the nuget powershell console by one of these methods :

- double clicking on the file
- right click / open with
- custom action on the context menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We followed up on this question at http://nuget.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=239161.

To summarize, try using an init.ps1 file.  Look at the MvcScaffold package for a good example of this.

Comment: THat link is broken

Answer (score 3):

Since the previous answer was posted this very simple package came about which does exactly what is needed:

- http://lostechies.com/matthinze/2012/01/05/solutionscripts-little-scripts-for-the-nuget-console/
- https://bitbucket.org/mhinze/solutionscripts/src/d3651b843e3d/tools/init.ps1
- http://nuget.org/packages/solutionscripts

In short, install the package and place those scripts in a folder called `SolutionScripts`.

Comment: SolutionScripts is a brilliant idea; we are using Entity Framework Code First & Migrations, and remembering the commands to add migrations/update database is a bit painful... we will be using SolutionScripts to create a solution-specific alias.

Comment: Yes for my project set up I always end up having to specify the project name and start up project for the migration commands so it's nice to be able to alias it.